# Cordova vs Phonegap on Plugin, Support, Documentation, Updates

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, plugins

Knowing that Phonegap is built on top of Cordova.

I am having several issues with Phonegap after trying out different versions

1. phonegap is poorly documented as lot of their guides are still using Cordova cli, which should be switched to phonegap. Just see their guide on 3.2 and 3.4. 3.2 the website uses phonegap on cli, 3.4 it uses back Cordova on cli.
2. When building Phonegap 3.4 on eclipse, it is fine. But on Phonegap 3.3, the build process will always replace default files with those I have implemented or amended.
3. Plugin like pushplugin fails on phonegap 3.3 and 3.4 (is it only me?), there is no support or response in the forum
4. Any new updates on Cordova, we will have to wait for Phonegap for integration. Which in turns will creates bugs in our Phonegap plugins

Now i am thinking to use solely Cordova. But I have few inquires.

1. Can Cordova uses the plugin from Phonegap
2. Can Phonegap uses the plugin from Cordova
3. Is it worth for the conversion from Phonegap to Cordova? Is Cordova more stable then Phonegap in terms of support, updates and plugin availability?
4. Which tools have more users? Phonegap or Cordova ?
5. Can Cordova be compile through cloud? This is important as I do not own a MAC for building ios application.

Answer (score 1):

It is completely worth it to change from phonegap to cordova.

**1>Can Cordova uses the plugin from Phonegap or 2>Can Phonegap uses the plugin from Cordova**

As phonegap is build on top of cordova,All pluging available for phonegap is available in cordova.Infact phonegap uses many of cordova's plugins,it downloads from cordova's library when you try to download

**3>Is it worth for the conversion from Phonegap to Cordova? Is Cordova more stable then Phonegap in terms of support, updates and plugin availability?**

It is completely worth the transformation,because cordova is more stable and we have a new version for every single issue reported. The newer phonegap versions are basically build on top of newer cordova versions .

**4>Which tools have more users? Phonegap or Cordova ?**

Both tools have more or less equal number of users although Iam slightly biased towards cordova .The users who can afford set up of all platforms prompt towards cordova and others towards phonegap.

**5>Can Cordova be compile through cloud? This is important as I do not own a MAC for building ios application**

No there is no tool to compile a cordova project through cloud.Although I once tried uploading the www folder of cordova into phonegap cloud and got a perfect build for IOS and Android.You can try this with a sample cordova project and if you are satisfied with the result  you can migrate to cordova

Comment: Have u tried wmware to run Mac os and build IOS file?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the Cordova plugin registry http://plugins.cordova.io/#/ .  I believe all plugins that work for Phonegap will work Cordova. PhoneGap only has a few plugins available for Build because they have to check to make sure the plugin will work with their system but those plugins will still work in Cordova.  Phonegap and Cordova are basically the same.  Phonegap is just owned by Adobe and the major difference is that Phonegap has Phonegap Build.  I do not believe that Cordova can be complied through cloud tho I could be wrong about that.  There are several other cross platform tools you may want to look into if you are not comfortable with Cordova and Phonegap such as appgyver or kivy.